# fadeout time slipping jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been having a bit of trouble getting the following fadeout code to work as i'd like.

Both temporary divs ($tempBackgroundTop, $tempBackground) should fadeout at the same time but one is fading out at just before the other.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("a.trigger").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var speed = 1e3,
            $body = jQuery("body"),
            $background = jQuery("#background"),
            $page = jQuery("#page"),
            $tempBackgroundTop = jQuery("<div/>").attr("id", "tempBackgroundTop").addClass("blueTop"),
            $tempBackground = jQuery("<div/>").attr("id", "tempBackground").addClass("blue");

        $page.after($tempBackgroundTop).after($tempBackground);
        $body.removeClass("blue").addClass("turquoise");
        $background.removeClass("blueTop").addClass("turquoiseTop");

        jQuery.when($tempBackgroundTop.fadeOut(speed), $tempBackground.fadeOut(speed)).done(function () {

            $tempBackgroundTop.remove();
            $tempBackground.remove();

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is beacuse you are calling the `fadeout` one before the other, try this:

```
var $tobefaded = jQuery("#tempBackgroundTop, #tempBackground");

jQuery.when($tobefaded.fadeOut(speed)).done(function () {...
```

This should fade both of them at the same time.

Comment: Yeah... I tried this before but it still wasn't playing ball. Same difference in the fade animation.

Comment: @james, im not sure this should work, can you put some of the code into a fiddle to show me what you are seeing?

Comment: Here's a fiddle but I'd copy the code out of the browser as you can't see the difference with the viewport being too small.
http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/bNeHH/

Comment: @James, im not seeing the issue

Comment: Just tested it at home. Same issue. You need your vieport to be over 900px to be able to see the join.

Answer (score 0):

Each browsers will probably be different. Try adjusting the milliseconds passed in to get them synced.

Comment: That feels a bit hacky to me. It would be impossible to predict each browsers speed too.

Comment: @James I agree but if you increase the one that is fired off first by a few millisecond they should both end around the same time(or at least closer than they are.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery 1.6 to see if it solves the issue?  See this snippet from the release notes:

> **Synced Animations**
>
> In jQuery you can have multiple
>   animations running simultaneously
>   (even multiple on the same element,
>   animating different properties). In
>   1.6 we’ve introduced an enhancement that ensures that all animations are
>   synced to the same timer interval.
>   This had the potential to create
>   problems before as animations could
>   become slightly out-of-sync (even by a
>   couple milliseconds) resulting in
>   slightly “off” animations.

Comment: At kingjiv: Thanks but that's what I'm using.